# How to Pass Variables into iFrame all in jQueryFunction

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I wanted to fire iframes with different sources depending on a link that i click. I arrived at a situation where I can click on different links and I manage to fire the same iframe, which i hardcoded like below:

This is what works:

```
        $('.myLink').click(function(){
        var myFile = $(this).attr('videofile');
        var myPost = $(this).attr('myfile');
        var myWidth = Number($(this).attr('mywidth'));
        var myHeight = Number($(this).attr('myheight'));

        var myCode = '<iframe  height="800" width="800"         
        src="https://www.duolingo.com/" allowfullscreen></iframe>';

        $('#myPlayer').html(myCode);`
```

However, when i want to pass my variables into my my iframe so that different sources, heights and widths could be applied accroding to specified variables, it does not work even though the variables are defined well. It is the iframe that does not accept them.

```
        $('.myLink').click(function(){
        var myFile = $(this).attr('myfile');
        var myPost = $(this).attr('myfile');
        var myWidth = Number($(this).attr('mywidth'));
        var myHeight = Number($(this).attr('myheight'));

        var myCode = '<iframe  height="+'myHeight'+" width="+'myWidth'+"  
        src="+'myFile'+" allowfullscreen></iframe>';

        $('#myPlayer').html(myCode);`
```

`

My question is how to modify /write code in myCode variable so that i could pass the myFile, myWidth, myHeight variables into iframe like i did above in myCode variable to make the iframe work? It does not work with the way i passed the variables, and i am pretty sure i passed them correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I think your quotation marks are a bit jumbled. ES6 introduced [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals), which make this a bit easier.

Here's something you can fiddle (hoho) with:

```
const height = 100;
const width = 500;
$('#foo').html(`<iframe height="${height}" width="${width}" src="https://www.bing.com"></iframe>`);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/y19ma974/3/

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, however it still does not work, the iframe gets fired as if no values were passed. However, when i hardcode the source (src="https://www.bing.com"), the iframe works but no variables for width and hight are applied. Just like in the case with my quotations, which are fine, becuase i managed to fire other code with the variables successfully passed in. It just does not work with the iframe. It seems the iframe is intolerant of passing variables within jQuery